# Is it correct to write 'a marvellous games'?

Tags: articles

> Thomas Bach, President of the International Olympic committee, said they had been a marvellous games in a marvellous city.

from [the BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/course/towards-advanced/unit-8/session-2)

I searched for the original statement -assumed that this was a paraphrase- and I found [this](https://olympics.com/ioc/news/future-host-cities-ready-to-draw-inspiration-from-marvellous-rio-games):

> These were marvellous Games in the Marvellous City. Hopefully, you can carry the inspiration and energy that we saw in Brazil to the next host cities.

Is the first one incorrect? If not, why and how is it correct? Why is the noun 'games' capitalized in the 2nd sentence, to refer to **Olympic Games**?

Comment: Why would it be incorrect?  Marvellous is an adjective, modifying "Games".  The capitalisation is a bit random in the second quote, but that is the fault of the transcriber not the speaker.

Comment: @JamesK Actually the OP is correct: you should capitalize Games when you're talking about the Olympics, and failing to do so in the first quote is a mistake.

Comment: I was talking more about "Marvelous City"  I'm not aware of that being a proper noun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of those weird times when a word is both plural and singular at the same time. There is one single event called "the Olympic Games", which is made up of a series of multiple smaller events that could each be called a game.

So you can abbreviate "the Olympic Games" as just "the Games" and refer to it as a singular thing, which is what Mr. Bach did.  However, in this usage, "Games" should always be capitalized, as it is short for the proper noun. The first quote you gave is incorrect in failing to capitalize Games.

This usage is not unique to the Olympics. For example, the Highland Games in Scotland works the same way, and is often referred to in that area as simply "the Games".

Comment: Thank you Darth Pseudonym. But, would it be correct to write 'Thomas Bach, President of the International Olympic committee, said they had been a marvellous Games.' ? In other words, is it all right to keep 'a' even after capitalizing'games' ?

Comment: @orhantorun yes, you can use *a* there. It is only one instance of an Olympic Games of many, after all.

Comment: As Esther said.  The 2020 Olympic Games is *an* Olympic Games, but not the only one. "**The** marvelous Games" would be to say that all Olympics as a general thing are marvelous; it wouldn't be referring one among many.  "**A** marvelous Games" is saying this one in particular was good.